# Reading mounted curlftpfs directory results in "Input/output error"

Tags: linux, curl, ftp

I want to mount a remote FTP directory in linux. One of the main tools I found is `curlftpfs`.

However, when I mount the remote FTP directory and try to read its contents, I get the following error:

```
$ curlftpfs -o allow_other ftp://test.rebex.net testftp                                                                                
$ ls testftp 
ls: reading directory 'testftp': Input/output error
```

`test.rebex.net` is a publicly available FTP server. I also tried with several other servers and a private one, and got the same error. Using root, options like `ssl`, `ftp_port=-`, fully disabling firewall, running on a fresh new arch/manjaro system didn't help. Still, I can connect to those servers using filezilla or `ftp` tool.

The output when running with debug (`-d`) option (full output, not redacted or truncated):

```
$ curlftpfs -d ftp://test.rebex.net testftp
FUSE library version: 2.9.9
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
unique: 2, opcode: INIT (26), nodeid: 0, insize: 104, pid: 0
INIT: 7.39
flags=0x73fffffb
max_readahead=0x00020000
   INIT: 7.19
   flags=0x00000011
   max_readahead=0x00020000
   max_write=0x00020000
   max_background=0
   congestion_threshold=0
   unique: 2, success, outsize: 40
```

curlftpfs version used is `0.9.2`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `curlftpfs` does not support the newer standartized FTP command `MLSD` used to retrieve the directory list. Some servers (like the `test.rebex.net`) most likely do not support the older (and not standartized) `LIST -a` command. There are forks of `curlftpfs` supporting `MLSD` command (like [this](https://codeberg.org/MadMaverick9/curlftpfs-ng)), but I have not tried them.

Instead, I found an alternative for myself, `rclone`. It supports FUSE and FTP, and uses `MLSD` command.